# How to set Assigned Access for Edge Browser

Tags: powershell

I would like to set Edge as an Assigned Access to a User.

I'm using the following PowerShell Command:

```
Set-AssignedAccess -AppUserModelId Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge -UserName xy
```

But I always get the following error (translated from German):

> System error 1376 has occurred.
>
> The specified local group does not exist.
>
> New-CimInstance : A general error has occurred, for which
>   no specific error code is available.
>   C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\AssignedAccess\AssignedAccess.psm1:300
>   Zeichen:13
>   +             New-CimInstance -ClassName WEDL_AssignedAccess -Property  ...
>   +             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (WEDL_AssignedAccess:CimInstance) [New-CimInstance], CimException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MI RESULT 1,Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimCmdlets.NewCimInstanceCommand

The local user exists, and the app exists too. I also logged in with the user I want to set the assignedaccess to make sure the profile is set u0p correctly

This happened on two different Windows 10 (build 14393) machines

I'm on PSVersion:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $psversiontable.psversion.toString()
5.1.14393.1944
```

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: I have the same issue, it's on machines where it can't be set via the settings app either. Cant figure out what to do...

Comment: @DennisSmolek seems like no "real" browser is supported for this feature. only Windows-App browsers like shiye browser are supported.

Comment: We found it wasn't related to the app itself but a messed up config blocking ALL assigned access. Machines that were Win8 > Win10 started failing with this message. Once we did a totally fresh wipe it started working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ran in to this yesterday. From what i could tell the "local group" thats referenced is actually the admin group. 
I ran the following commands in an elevated powershell prompt:

**Net localgroup administrators /add**.

This creates a local Administrators group.

**Net localgroup administratörer administrators /add**.

This adds the administrators group to the local admin group (Administratörer is the Swedish localization of Administrators, use the local version depending on your country and replace it).

After this is done, run your previous commands.

Give it a try, hope it helps :)

//Chris

Comment: yes, this actually works! your administrator needs to be in a group called administrators - in my swiss-german environment this group is called Administratoren, so i had to create administrators by myself and add my admins into this group. since then - it worked!

Comment: btw: these days (win10 1903), searching for `kiosk` in windows-settings lets you have more options than `Set-AssignedAccess` cmdlet. go this way

Answer (score 0):

Set-AssignedAccess -UserName weakusername -AUMID Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge

Comment: The above doesn't work. The same error message is displayed when tested using Windows 10 Enterprise 1709.